# How does SQL Server implicit type casting work in this case?

Tags: sql-server, implicit-conversion

When I try this ad-hoc query in SQL Server (assume `UserId` is a NVARCHAR field):

```
SELECT * FROM MyUser WHERE UserId = 123456
```

I get this error:

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Syntax error converting the nvarchar value 'foo' to a column of data type int.
```

Obviously there is a value `'foo'` somewhere down my `UserId` column.

Why is SQL Server trying to convert my entire column to INTEGER instead of doing what seems obvious to me: converting my search value to NVARCHAR?

Comment: I don't know why it's doing it. But that's what it always does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison is done using the rules of [Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx):

> When an operator combines two
>   expressions of different data types,
>   the rules for data type precedence
>   specify that the data type with the
>   lower precedence is converted to the
>   data type with the higher precedence.

The `NVARCHAR` type (precedence 25) is converted to `int` (precedence 16). Note that precedence 1 means 'highest'.

Comment: +1 That is exactly what I tried to explain, somehow, in my own words. Thanks for this great link! =)

Comment: I think this is something the query optimizer should be able to handle before it passes the query into the engine: Convert my search value to a type that would work, issue a warning about it and let me get away with it. Ah well. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because it cannot compare two values of different types. Then, is has to convert either  equality comparsion members to the same type. Here, `int` is prefered, I guess.

I believe an `int` has a precedence over the `nvarchar` type, so it must implicitly try to convert the `nvarchar` to the int value.

**EDIT #1**

> "But wouldn't it be sensible to try and convert the value I have given to the type of the field I am searching in, instead of the other way around?"

Yes, this would be nice if it did. But I guess that is because there would be too much conversion tries to imply when trying some other sort of comparison.

```
where dateOfBirth = 1976-6-16
```

vs

```
where dateOfBirth = N'1976-06-16'
```

In first example, what is the intention of the user? Is it to verify whether `dateOfBirth` is equals to the date value of `1976-06-16` or to compare with an integer value of `1976 - 6 - 16`, which would result to `1954`, which could be reasonable enough to consider it as the year of a any given date.

I think there is implicit conversions such `nvarchar` to `datetime`, but there would be much to cover, so they limited themselves to the most common possible conversion.

Comment: But wouldn't it be sensible to try and convert the value I have given to the type of the field I am searching in, instead of the other way around?

Comment: Yeah. It's annoying because it seems to deliberately avoid using the index by doing this -- even if you've got a primary key on UserID and look for one that's in the table, you may still find the result, but you'll also hit the error (i.e. you'll get a result row returned _as well_ as an error from a different row that doesn't match.) Oracle does this too, and I've never seen a great deal of sense in it; I guess it's just a side-effect of the default type promotion/conversion rules.

Comment: The intention of `where dateOfBirth = 1976-6-16` clearly is the arithmetic result of `1976 - 6 - 16`. DATETIME is a numeric type, the user gave a numeric input (an expression, but nevertheless). If I give it a string (`N'1976-06-16'`), the server *obviously* converts it to DATETIME before using it, otherwise these queries wouldn't work. So it could in fact be smart enough to do the same thing in the situation described in my question. ;-) But I do appreciate that things are the way they are.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you specifying an integer value if you know the column is NVARCHAR?

Unfortunately SQL Server, like many SQL implementations, is a long way behind other languages in its type support. Type checking is usually only performed at runtime. So queries like yours aren't syntax checked to highlight problems like the one you have here. Your query is at fault because you are mismatching different types, but because SQL Server doesn't vaidate it the results will be unpredictable, depending on the data.

Comment: Why? Because it was an ad-hoc query and I didn't think of typing the quotes this time. I was just surprised by the immense stupidity of the error message and wondered if there was a deeper rationale behind it. Turns out, there isn't – it "just is that way".

Comment: @Tomalak: A much better error message would be "type mismatch" - but the resolution would still be the same: fix your query to specify the right type of value.

Comment: I didn't mean to say the *wording of the message* was stupid, I'm saying the way SQL Server *handles the situation* is stupid. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: What's really stupid is that SQL Server supports implict type conversions at all (or at least that it has no way to enforce strict typing). Your suggestion that SQL Server should guess what you meant by this query and presumably NOT return an error would be just as bad - if not worse. Implict type conversion ought to be disallowed, just as it is in most modern languages.

Comment: Well, actually… SQL Server *knows* the target column is VARCHAR, conversion from INTEGER to VARCHAR is losslessly possible and it could even use an index if the search argument was VARCHAR. Clearly, it would not have to guess. It could issue a warning about the implicit type cast and let me get on with my life. Trying to convert all column values to INT instead is dumb, there is no way denying that. Regarding duck-typing: Matter of preference, I guess. Interpreted languages tend to benefit from it, complied languages rather don't.