# SQL query runs 10 times slower with certain value when using variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

**EDIT**: No result in `DB1.dbo.TABLE_B` with `STRING_ID ='id009'` or `'id008'`; `STRING_ID` is `varchar(100)` and is not unique.

**EDIT2**: Execution plan for both queries are same.

I have a query below running on a SQL Server 2008 server:

```
DECLARE @stringid nvarchar(10)
SET @stringid='id009'
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.TABLE_A
         INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.TABLE_B
         ON DB1.dbo.TABLE_A.ID=DB1.dbo.TABLE_B.ID
WHERE DB1.dbo.TABLE_B.STRING_ID=@stringid
ORDER BY DB1.dbo.TABLE_B.UID desc, DB1.dbo.TABLE_A.TIME desc
```

This query will take 10 seconds to get the result (which is empty).

If I change the second line of this query to use any other value e.g.

```
SET @stringid='id008'
```

The query will get the result instantly (empty result as well).

**More importantly:** If I change the query to not use the variable but just pass the value ('id009') as below:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.TABLE_A
         INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.TABLE_B
         ON DB1.dbo.TABLE_A.ID=DB1.dbo.TABLE_B.ID
WHERE DB1.dbo.TABLE_B.STRING_ID='id009'
ORDER BY DB1.dbo.TABLE_B.UID desc, DB1.dbo.TABLE_A.TIME desc
```

The query will also get the result instantly (empty result).

So my question is why is this query running so slow with variable set to that certain value?

Comment: How many rows are there in `TABLE_B` with `STRING_ID='id009'`, and how many with `STRING_ID='id008'`?

Comment: Probably something to do with the table statistics. Try turning on graphical query plans and see if the plans differ between the first two cases you describe. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @Bolu Empty result or empty `TABLE_B`?

Comment: what is the data type of TABLE_B.STRING_ID? Also are the string ids unique or allowed to have multiple?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, Empty reslut

Comment: @Bolu I asked about `TABLE_B`, not result of the query above.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, see my update, empty result in table_B. table_B itself is not empty but has no record matching `string_id='id009' or 'id008'`.

Comment: @Bolu OK, just to make it clear: `SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE string_id='id009'` returns zero rows, correct?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic, correct

Comment: @Bolu you are declaring the var as nvarchar(10). What is the datatype for TABLE_B.STRING_ID that you are comparing the var against? If the types differ and an implicit casting takes place it could account for delays even when having different values.

Comment: @gts, it's varchar(100) and is not unique.

Comment: Have you heard anything about parameter sniffing? search on google for  the same, you will know solution of your problem.

Comment: @Bolu can you try having the same data type between the two? Either by changing the var's type or the column's one

Comment: @gts, you know what... SPOT ON!! but why just for one value? why using other values e.g. `id008` can get the result instantly?

Comment: @Bolu, strange are the ways of the MSSQL. My suggestion was to simply compare vars of the same type instead of relying on some invisible internal implicit casting where something may go wrong

Comment: @Bolu I've created an answer so that it serves as reference for people having the same prob in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are declaring the var as nvarchar(10). Make sure that the datatype for TABLE_B.STRING_ID is the same or that the @stringid var has the same datatype as TABLE_B.STRING_ID. If the types differ and an implicit casting takes place it could account for delays even when having different values.

Some useful info on MSSQL type casting also at [How does SQL Server implicit type casting work in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227315/how-does-sql-server-implicit-type-casting-work-in-this-case)

Comment: many thanks! Just to confirm, when I change `@stringid` to `varchar`, it gets me the result instantly!!!

Comment: You may wish to compare query plans between the various queries to gain further insight.

Comment: the execution plan for both queries was stated to be the same